# JQuery fails to render to page, but no errors

Tags: jquery

I'm using JQuery to modify and replace the following HTML

```
<div class="weather-feed">
    <img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/32.gif"/><br />
    <b>Current Conditions:</b><br />
    Sunny, 17 C<BR />
    <BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />
    Wed - Mostly Sunny. High: 27 Low: 14<br />
    Thu - Mostly Sunny. High: 25 Low: 14<br />
    Fri - Partly Cloudy. High: 26 Low: 15<br />
    Sat - Partly Cloudy. High: 27 Low: 17<br />
    Sun - Partly Cloudy. High: 28 Low: 17<br />
    <br />
    <a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Pretoria__SF/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/SFXX0044_c.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>
    (provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>
</div>
```

This code is retrieved onto the page (into the div specifically) through a PHP Session. The div is just there to help with selection (and styling later on).

Because a lot of this HTML doesn't have any identifiable containers, I'm using regex to isolate certain text (such as the weather conditions and forecast):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var src = $(".weather-feed");

    // remove line feeds
    src.find("br").remove();

    // get weather conditions    
    var result = "<div class=\"weather-conditions\">";
    result += src.html().match(/<\/b>([^<]*)<b>/)[1].trim();
    result += "</div>";

    // get weather icon
    result += "<div class=\"weather-icon\"><img src=\"" + src.find("img").attr("src") + "\" /><span><?php echo($city); ?></span></div>";

    // more button
    result += "<div class=\"weather-more-button\">+</div>";

    // get weather forecast
    result += "<div class=\"weather-extra\">";
    result += "<div class=\"weather-forecast\">";
    result += src.html().match(/<\/b>([^<]*)<a/)[1].trim().replace("\n", "<br />");
    result += "</div>"; 

    // get addition forecast link
    result += "<div class=\"weather-detail\">";
    result += $("<div/>").html(src.find('a').first()).html();
    result += "</div></div>";

    console.log(result);

    // write new code to page           
    src.empty();
    src.append(result);
});
```

Unfortunately, while the jquery produces no errors and logs `result` correctly (see below) to the console, the new code isn't rendered to the page. All I'm seeing there is still the original code returned by the PHP.

```
<div class="weather-conditions">
    Sunny, 17 C
</div>
<div class="weather-icon">
    <img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/32.gif" />
    <span>Pretoria</span>
</div>
<div class="weather-more-button">+</div>
<div class="weather-extra">
    <div class="weather-forecast">
        Wed - Mostly Sunny. High: 27 Low: 14<br />
        Thu - Mostly Sunny. High: 25 Low: 14
        Fri - Partly Cloudy. High: 26 Low: 15
        Sat - Partly Cloudy. High: 27 Low: 17
        Sun - Partly Cloudy. High: 28 Low: 17
    </div>
    <div class="weather-detail">
        <a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Pretoria__SF/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/SFXX0044_c.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Additionally (and I think there's a good chance it's related), the replacement of `\n` with `<br />` under the weather forecast section isn't working for more than the 1st match and I'm at a loss as to why that is.

If anyone can assist here in any way, I'd really appreciate it.

Here's a Fiddle so you can see what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/4UyAj/

Comment: are you trying to change content inside iframe?

Comment: No, but again it seems my question was posted prematurely. The div is using `.weather-feed` and the css that styles it targets `#weather-feed`

Comment: Tip: Don't build strings with `+= ... += ... += ...`, which is wasteful of RAM. Instead, push each text fragment onto an array and finally `.join('')` all the pieces together.

Comment: Maybe more importantly, what's the scenario here? You mention a PHP Session, indicating that you have control server-side. Why mess around client-side when you could serve exactly what is required in the first place?

Comment: Also, if you must do this client-side, don't forget that jQuery's `.html()` returns totally synthetic HTML - not what was originally used to render the page - therefore unreliable when submitted to a regexp.

Comment: Ortund, is this solved?